# What is the Pythonic way to use (elements of) a list as keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given the list:

```
keys = ['Orange','Blue','Green']
```

and the dictionary

```
colors = {}
```

What is the most Pythonic way to use (the elements of) `keys` as the keys to `colors`? I'm currently doing the following but want to know if there's a better way of using Python than this.

```
for key in keys:
    colors[key] = []
```

**EDIT**: The question originally asked for "the most Pythonic way to use `keys` as the keys to `colors`", but the subsequent code snippet indicates that what's actually required is a way to use its elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use dict comprehensions:

```
In [1]: keys = ['Orange', 'Blue', 'Green']

In [2]: colors={key: [] for key in keys}

In [3]: colors
Out[3]: {'Blue': [], 'Green': [], 'Orange': []}
```

for python 2.6:

```
In [4]: colors = dict((key, []) for key in keys)

In [5]: colors
Out[5]: {'Blue': [], 'Green': [], 'Orange': []}
```

Answer (score 6):

If order matters, use a `tuple`.

```
In [113]: keys = ['Orange','Blue','Green']

In [114]: colors = {}

In [115]: colors[tuple(keys)] = 0

In [116]: colors
Out[116]: {('Orange', 'Blue', 'Green'): 0}
```

If order does not matter, use a `frozenset`. A `frozenset` essentially gives you a hashable `set`, which can't be modified and yet has all the advantages of a `set` (O(1) lookup, etc)

```
In [117]: colors = {}

In [118]: colors[frozenset(keys)] = 0

In [119]: colors
Out[119]: {frozenset(['Orange', 'Blue', 'Green']): 0}
```

If you want each element in `keys` to be a key in `colors`:

```
In [120]: colors = {k:[] for k in keys}

In [121]: colors
Out[121]: {'Blue': [], 'Green': [], 'Orange': []}
```

Comment: `s/order/order and\/or presence of duplicates/g`

Comment: It looks like he wants to use each element of the list as a key, whereas this answer would apply if he wanted to use the list itself as a key.

Comment: thank you for this answer - it taught me something new and interesting.

Answer (score 6):

Dict comprehensions as mentioned above are the way to go. In the interest of showing alternatives, you could also use a `defaultdict` in combination with `fromkeys` if you want to instantiate with a list:

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: keys = ['Orange','Blue','Green']

In [3]: colors = defaultdict.fromkeys(keys, list)

In [4]: colors['Orange']
Out[4]: <type 'list'>
```